# wget -i - ./directory

Tags: stdin, wget

What does it do? I read that it downloads things from Stdin, but where do you actually need it?

**Conclusion**

```
some_program | wget -i - -P ./directory
```

wget gets urls as Stdin from some_program. The input will result in output generated by wget to ./directory.

```
wget -i ./file
```

The above command gets urls form ./file, and it generates output to the current directory. The crux difference is the lack of - sign to the above command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can imagine it being useful when piping output from another program:

```
linkdiscoverer | wget -i - ./directory
```

(For some suitable `linkdiscoverer` program.)

I'm not sure the `./directory` bit is really what you want though. Did you mean to use `-P ./directory` to save files into the specified directory?

Comment: @ST: -i means "download URLs from a file, while -P means apparently "save files to the directory" --- This means that John is right because of your statement"downloading things from Stdin".

Answer (score 0):

> I read that it downloads things from Stdin, but where do you actually need it?

Maybe re-read man pages again:

```
‘-i file’
‘--input-file=file’
    Read urls from file. If ‘-’ is specified as file, urls are read from the standard input. (Use ‘./-’ to read from a file literally named ‘-’.)
```